# How to keep custom cursors even when hovering on links?

Tags: html, css

For my website I have such code:

```
html {
  cursor: url(cursor.cur), progress !important;
}
```

obviously in a style rule. How do I do a rule which has a similar effect to the following one:

```
a:hover {
 cursor: url(cursor.cur), progress !important;
}
```

but which actually works. It seemed to work in Safari, but it didn't work in Chrome 17.0.963.78 for Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me in Chrome 19.0.1061.1.dev on Mac. So it's possibly a bug in 17.0.963.78.

http://jsfiddle.net/q2yZg/ that I used for tests.